# What words mean ''you inadvertently said something inappropriate, embarrassing, tactless, etc"?

Tags: word-request

In situations when someone has said something that he/she didn't realize was inappropriate, embarrassing, tactless, what word should I use to describe it?

Comment: Do you mean they do not realize it is bad _before_ they say it? Or do you mean that even after they say it, they _still_ do not realize it is bad until you explicitly tell them?

Comment: @MJ713 Like when someone has realized what he/she has just said when they've said it

Answer (score 1):

**To put your foot in it / to put your foot in your mouth** is to accidentally say something that is embarrassing or that upsets or annoys someone:

> Jack really put his foot in it by telling Alice about the surprise party.
>
> I really put my foot in my mouth – I asked her if Jane was her mother, but she said Jane is her sister.

Comment: For the askers interest, "put your foot in it" is the older expression. Its etymology probably relates to accidentally standing in dung or a muddy puddle or something, the idea behind the metaphor that stepping in dung is an embassing act.

Answer (score 1):

You can say they've committed a ***gaffe*** or a ***faux pas*** (from French).